# How do I copy files from project directory to outside project directory?

Tags: build, copy, scons

Scons `Copy` builder doesn't do anything when the path I want to copy **to** points outside the project directory. Is there any way to get it to actually do it? Below is more or less the test case:

```py
p4_dir = '../../../documents'

def prefix_dir(files, *directory):
    if not type(directory) is tuple:
        directory = (directory,)
    return [os.path.realpath(
        os.path.join(*(directory + (f,))).replace('\\', '/')) for f in files]

def p4doc():
    for x, y in zip(prefix_dir(p4_goodies, Dir('.').abspath, p4_dir), p4_goodies):
        print 'copying to: %s from: %s' % (x, y)
        Command(x, y, [Delete("$TARGET"), Copy("$TARGET", "$SOURCE")])

p4doc()
```

Besides, when it copies, it doesn't really copy the files it's told to copy, it takes all the targets given to the builder, which calls this action... You can substitute `$TARGET` and `$SOURCE` in the `Copy` command with any string. Given it doesn't have double dots in it, all builder's sources will be copied. Now this isn't just wrong... this is stupid by design :|

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Install() builder](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/c2938.html). The files it copies/installs should be SCons targets and if they're not, they probably wont be copied.

Comment: @wvxvw, well it all stems from 2 SCons concepts: its designed to only work on dirs/files in the same dir or a subdir of where the SConstruct is, and it typically only works on SCons target files.